# Kiselev's Geometry: Find a point $C$ such that the sum $CA + CB$ is congruent to a given segment.

Tags: geometry

> I am trying to solve exercise 139 from Kiselev's *Geometry Book 1. Planimetry*

Given a point $A$ on one of the sides of an angle $B$. On the other side of the angle, find a point $C$ such that the sum $CA + CB$ is congruent to a given segment.

The exercise comes after a section on basic construction problems using a straight edge and compass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Diagram for given question]

Given any length *l*, we can line it up to angle B to produce a length *BA'*. Drawing an isosceles trangle with *AA'* as its base and one angle *BA'A*, we produce a fixed point C that satisfies your conditions. Can you see why your given length must be greater than the length *BA*?

Comment: Is it because the given length must be greater than the length $BA$ in order to satisfy the triangle inequality? Thank you for your clear answer.

Comment: Yes, exactly right.